# GnuPG decryption not asking for passphrase

Tags: encryption, pgp, gnupg

I've some stuff encrypted with GnuPG using `gpg -e`. When I decrypt them, the system does not ask for the passphrase, it decrypts it straight away.

Does it store the secret key somewhere and uses it (I also stored my secret key in the GnuPG key chain, does it uses that)?

How can I force the system to ask the passphrase every time?

Comment: This irritating behaviour may also occur when using `--symmetric` / `-c`, which doesn't use any keys from the keyring. The accepted answer also works for that case.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395875/gpg-does-not-ask-for-password

Comment: To force it to ask for the passphrase just when you want it to, for testing, do this: To force it to ask for a passphrase, do this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543856/114401

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Does it store the secret key somewhere and uses it (I also stored my secret key in the GnuPG key chain, does it uses that)?

GnuPG only uses keys from your key chain, so it *must* be in there to use it.

> How can I force the system to ask the passphrase every time?

Old versions of GnuPG uses the `gpg-agent`, which caches the passphrase for a given time. Use the option `--no-use-agent` or add a line `no-use-agent` to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` to prevent using the agent.

For newer versions (v2.1+), disable password caching for the agent by creating `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and adding the following lines:

```
default-cache-ttl 1
max-cache-ttl 1
```

Restart the agent with:

```
echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
```

Comment: Note that for gpg2 "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect.

Comment: To be more specific, it is obsolete for GnuPG 2.1 (and newer).

Comment: `0` seems to mean no caching at all, as it correctly asks for passphrase even immediately after encrypting. I just wanted to add that [the correct way to reload gpg-agent](http://superuser.com/a/521027/281818) would be `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent`

Comment: It might be noteworthy that `gpg-agent` also caches passphrases used with `gpg --symmetric`, which allows anyone with access to the shell / `gpg-agent`-session to decrypt the file *without* entering the passphrase.

Comment: what should one do in gpg2 ?

Comment: @EsseTi to achieve what outcome? `max-cache-tl 0` should still be valid with any recent GnuPG version.

Comment: Just to be clear, `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` probably needs to be created.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all users, for the newer gpg?

Comment: GnuPG does not read a system-wide configuration file, so you need to roll out the configuration for all existing users and create it when creating new users (skeleton folder on Linux, don't know how to do so in Windows).

Comment: I only know of the "set cache period to 1sec" method already described in the answer.

Comment: I use GPG suite on macos, and setting these options has no effect. Neither `gpg -s` nor `pass` (which allegedly uses gpg) prompt for a password.

Answer (score 15):

GnuPG 2.2.15

> ```
>   --symmetric
>           -c  Encrypt with a symmetric cipher using a passphrase. The default sym-
>           metric cipher used is AES-128, but may be chosen with the  --cipher-algo
>           option.  This command may be combined with --sign (for a signed and sym-
>           metrically encrypted message), --encrypt (for  a  message  that  may  be
>           decrypted  via  a  secret  key or a passphrase), or --sign and --encrypt
>           together (for a signed message that may be decrypted via a secret key or
>           a  passphrase).  gpg caches the passphrase used for symmetric encryption
>           so that a decrypt operation may not require that the user needs to enter
>           the  passphrase.   The  option  --no-symkey-cache can be used to disable
>           this feature.
> ```

```
# encrypt files
gpg -c --no-symkey-cache file.txt
# decrypt files
gpg --no-symkey-cache file.txt.gpg
```

with --no-symkey-cache option, it will not cache your password

Comment: This works, but if I switch to another user, like root, it doesn't work--I get the error "gpg: problem with the agent: Permission denied" BUT there is a solution, "pinentry mode" `gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback test.gpg` https://askubuntu.com/a/1158297/429995

Comment: Although the man page doesn't mention it, you also need --no-symkey-cache when decrypting, as shown in this example.

Answer (score 5):

Encrypting a "test" file should give us test.gpg

`# gpg -c test`

But no, we get some errors.

```
gpg: problem with the agent: Permission denied
gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled
gpg: symmetric encryption of 'test' failed: Operation cancelled
```

Loopback mode to the rescue!

```
# gpg -c --pinentry-mode=loopback test
```

It prompts for your password and works as expected.

When it comes time to decrypt, maybe you change users and get an error:

```
gpg: problem with the agent: Permission denied
```

Loopback mode to the rescue!

```
# gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback test.gpg
```

Tested with...

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.20
libgcrypt 1.8.5
```

IMO `--pinentry-mode=loopback` and `--no-symkey-cache` should be the default settings. I found the solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/1158297/429995 and the "anonymous" answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/221766/95763) (to not cache the password) was helpful as well.

Comment: `--no-symkey-cache` is not an option in version `2.2.5`.

Answer (score 0):

For gpg version 2.2.4 the following work using symmetric and adding --batch to the **gpg** command:

Therefore, to clear the password stored in the session, we can run:

`echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent`

More info in this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/encrypt-decrypt-files

Answer (score 0):

Some pinentry implementations cache the decryption keys in the desktops keystore, you can disable that functionality by using `--no-allow-external-cache` ([documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#index-no_002dallow_002dexternal_002dcache)):

> Tell Pinentry not to enable features which use an external cache for passphrases.
>
> Some desktop environments prefer to unlock all credentials with one master password and may have installed a Pinentry which employs an additional external cache to implement such a policy. By using this option the Pinentry is advised not to make use of such a cache and instead always ask the user for the requested passphrase.