# gpg4win kleopatra doesn't ask for passphrase on subsequent runs

Tags: gnupg, windows-7

Am using gpg4win kleopatra for encrypting files.  After bootup when I try to decrypt a previously encrypted file, it asks for a passphrase as expected. But after some time, if again I try decrypting a file it doesn't ask for passphrase and directly decrypts it. I don't what the gpg agent to remember my passphrase.

How to change this setting?

I checked the following check boxes:

- Do not use pin caching while signing
- Disallow the use of external password cache.

Even after selecting the above checkboxes it asked for passphrase once. But immediately after that, it decrypted without prompting for a passphrase.

I checked the existing post link below, but that explains only for Linux. Doesn't talk about the Windows gpg agent.

Comment: See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/103037/95810

Answer (score 12):

This is controlled by the following setting:

Kleopatra Settings > GnuPG System > GPG Agent > Expire cached PINs after N seconds

Set it to 0 to make the cached password forgotten immediately.

Answer (score 8):

The settings have moved. Now it's under:

"GnuPG System" -> Private Keys -> "Expire cached PINs after N Seconds" and "Set maximum PIN cache lifetime to N seconds".

Or you can write it directly to the config in %APPDATA%/gpg-agent.conf

```
default-cache-ttl 72000
max-cache-ttl 72000
```

source: https://dev.gnupg.org/T4449

Comment: This is it, thank you very much!