# How to pass both passphrase and password in GPG signed symmetric encryption?

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg, file-encryption

I am new to GPG so I may be going about this all wrong.  I have some files I would like to encrypt symmetrically using AES256, but I want to sign them with my GPG key.  I need to automate this process however so I'm using `--batch` and I pass the symmetric key after `--passphrase`.  Since it needs to be automated, I've disabled passphrase caching by following the steps [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/103037/116877).  However, this means my script has no way to pass in the passphrase for my GPG private key.  My script will be piping the files to gpg so passing the passphrase to gpg via stdin is also not an option.

If there is no reasonable way to pass both the AES password and private key passphrase, I might consider doing this in two steps, with gpg symmetrically encrypting and then a second round of gpg for signing.  It seems excessive though, considering gpg can clearly do this in one step if one passes the private key passphrase interactively.

For reference, I'm using gpg2 exclusively and don't care about backwards compatibility with gpg 1.x.

Here is the command I'm currently using for encryption.  It encrypts and signs as expected, but I can only pass it the private key's passphrase interactively in the text-based dialog "window".

`gpg2 --batch --passphrase <my-long-symmetric-password> --sign --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 plaintext.txt`

Comment: when i use `gpg --passphrase` it doesn't prompt me for the password.

Comment: @john doe It appears taking advantage of gpg-agent is a good approach to this problem.  Your comment was a good clue.

Answer (score 1):

I found I was going about this all wrong and I found `gpg-preset-passphrase`, which seems to be for prepopulating passphrases in gpg-agent, meaning gpg2 won't ask for a passphrase as long as I call `gpg-preset-passphrase` from my script before running the gpg2 encrypt-and-sign I posted in my question.  Just make sure to start `gpg-agent` with a very high `--max-cache-ttl` to be certain the cache won't expire before the script finishes.  After that, running `gpg-preset-passphrase --forget` is a good idea to make sure the passphrase doesn't stay cached too long.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to pass the password in the command. You want to input the password on stdin, so that the password isn't recorded to disk, which it will be if its passed directly in a command. If its recorded to disk, any program with permissions could dump that passphrase and easily access your private keys. The current configuration where you input the password on stdin is the recommended process.

Comment: I know passing passwords on the command line is not particularly secure, but this is running on a dedicated VM and the data being encrypted isn't particularly sensitive.  In this case, I'd prefer sacrificing a little bit of security in exchange for convenience.  If I did care enough about protecting the key, I'd use the `--passphrase-file` option, with very restrictive permissions.